# How do I change temperature units in "Discovery"?

Tags: location-services, google-assistant

I'm using a Pixel 3a, with Android 11. I have Google Assistant disabled in general, but occassionally go through the articles section that's still available and sometimes stumble upon the "Discovery" tab in other ways.

Recently, a weather/temperature bubble showed up in the corner of the assistant's "Discovery" tab:

[image]

Now I don't understand °F and would like to switch the bubble over to °C units. I can't figure out how to do that.

- The weather widget on my home screen already shows temperature in °C.
- The notifications for "Current weather conditions" are in °C as well.
- If I click on this bubble to open full weather information, that *also* uses °C.
- I even have location enabled, letting the weather page guess my current location.

  (Although the current-weather notifications do insist that I live in another town a few kilometers away from where I live, with "AGPS reset" only helping for a few minutes, but at least it still gets the city right, so surely that shouldn't be the problem.)
- My *Play Store* country is still set correctly.
- Geolocation websites recognize my IP address correctly.

Is there any setting that I'm missing? Do I need to re-enable the full Google Assistant to find it? I don't really care about this weather bubble in itself (it just shows the same thing I already see otherwise), but the *inability to change it* annoys me every time.

Comment: [From 3 dots menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L4ax.png)

Comment: I don't have that menu, I only have the tiny "73° F" bubble shown in the screenshot and nothing more.